# How do you get the style of focussed HTML element using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, focus, puppeteer

I would like to get the computed style of an element when it is focussed. I am using puppeteer and I would like to compare the CSS before focus to the CSS after focus. I can successfully get focus on an element using `element.focus()` and can confirm it's focussed by checking the active element (document.activeElement). However, the computed style (`getComputedStyle()`) for this element is the same as before focus, which is not what I expected.

Is there a way to get the CSS of the element after focus?

To be clear, I am writing a JavaScript tool which can scrape any website  to check if the outline or border of an element under focus has sufficient contrast with the background on the page (such that it conforms with accessibility guidelines https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/non-text-contrast.html). To do this I need to be able to get the colour of the outline/border when the element is under focus. Normally a focus outline would be defined in the CSS under `:focus { ... }` so this is what I wish to retrieve for any element.

Comment: as I know, focus is more like element state instead of style. http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Javascript/Javascript_Reference/CSSStyleDeclaration/Property_list_in_CSSStyleDeclaration.htm

Comment: Whatt do you expect the css to become after focus?

Comment: A common occurrence is for the border or outline to become blue on a selected element. This is what I would expect. @GetSet

Comment: @demkovych Is there a way to retrieve the style of the element when it's in that state? e.g. the outline of a button may change to blue when it is in the focus state. But when I get the computed style of that element while it's in that state, the style does not say that the outline is blue.

Comment: Hello, does my answer below (https://stackoverflow.com/a/59944379/9060223) help?

Comment: It seemed to work in browser but from puppeteer I had no success. Not sure why.

Comment: Hi Jason, Did you get the answer to your question? It would be great if you can comment below your approach since I have the same problem.

Comment: Unfortunately I did not find a solution for this, but I did not see Richard's solution below so perhaps that is worth trying. @Manav

Answer (score 0):

you need to pay attention to the order of code in the script. if you change the style before the `getComputedStyle()` you'll get the change.

exmple:

```js
document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("focus", (e) => {
  console.log(window.getComputedStyle(e.target, null).color);
  e.target.style.color = "red";
  console.log(window.getComputedStyle(e.target, null).color);
  e.target.style.color = "blue";
})
```

```html
<input type="text" style="color: blue;">
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I don't think this will help because I wish to be able to scrape any website to get the focus outline that they have defined. I have added to my question so hopefully it is clearer what I wish to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

As `getComputedStyle` returns a live `CSSStyleDeclaration`, you have to record the CSS styles by yourself manually to keep the CSS before focus.

Here's a working example:

```js
let allInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input')
let beforeFocusStyles = Array.from(allInputs).reduce(function(final, elem) {
  final[elem.dataset.identifier] = (function() {
    let liveStyle = window.getComputedStyle(elem)
    let value = {}
    for (let key in liveStyle) {
      value[key] = liveStyle[key]
    }
    return value
  })()
  return final
}, {})

Array.from(allInputs).forEach(elem => {
  elem.onfocus = function() {
    let afterFocusStyle = window.getComputedStyle(elem)
    let differenceInStyle = (function() {
      let beforeFocusStyle = beforeFocusStyles[elem.dataset.identifier]
      let differences = []
      for (let key in afterFocusStyle) {
        if (beforeFocusStyle[key] !== afterFocusStyle[key]) {
          differences.push([key, beforeFocusStyle[key], afterFocusStyle[key]])
        }
      }
      return differences
    })()

    differenceInStyle.forEach(difference => {
      console.log(difference[0], difference[1], difference[2])
    })
  }
})
```

```css
.type1 {
  outline: 1px solid black;
  border: none;
}

.type1:focus {
  outline: 2px solid red;
  border: none;
}

.type2 {
  outline: 1px solid blue;
  border: none;
}

.type2:focus {
  outline: 2px solid green;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="type1" data-identifier="1">
<input type="text" class="type2" data-identifier="2">
```